# Workflow Designer drop activity in designer programmatically?

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

I have used Workflow designer and Toolbox; I want to add activity to workflow designer when double click happened on Toolbox ? I want to drop that activity on workflow designer...

Comment: Which Workflow Designer are you using? OSWorkflow? http://www.opensymphony.com/osworkflow/designer/

Comment: Jared, I am using WorkflowDesigner in WF4...

Answer (score 0):

The worklfow designer does so by default in VS2010 and as the rehosted designer is the same thing I would expect the same behavior here, not really sure if it does though. If it doesn't you can do whatever you like, and that includes adding activities to the design surface, in code.

Comment: Do you have code sample for adding activities to Designer surface programmatically ? Along with this I want to ensure that ModelService_ModelChange event is also invoked ?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the AssociatedDesigner property of the ToolboxControl and double clicking will start working.